# How to close parent window when child window is closed in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, authentication, tkinter

i am making a GUI and in it I am keeping the root hidden. So when i close the window which is showing using the x arrow, i wont the whole program to end not just the window that can be seen. Because other wise the user will have problems when closing the program.my root is hidden,
login can be seen,
when login is closed using the red x at the top i want to close the root as well how to do that?

Comment: Try `window.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', root.destroy)` where `window` is the opened window and `root` is the root window.  Note that it only works for the close button on the title bar of the opened window.

Comment: @acw1668 yeah that worked fine thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the `<Destroy>` event on your window. Within the bound function, you can do whatever you want including destroying the root window.

In the following example, killing the `Toplevel` windows will destroy the root window.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, root, label):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.root = root
        label = tk.Label(self, text=label)
        label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

        self.bind("<Destroy>", self.kill_root)

    def kill_root(self, event):
        if event.widget == self and self.root.winfo_exists():
            self.root.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="Root window")
label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

w1 = Window(root, "This is a toplevel window")

root.mainloop()
```

The reason for checking that `event.widget` is `self` is due to the fact that functions bound to the root or toplevel window are automatically inherited by all children within that window You only want to destroy the root window when the actual toplevel window is destroyed.

Comment: i am not using obj oriented programming, is it possible to do it without that?

Comment: @GauravSuvarna Yes, of course. The bindings don't care if you use classes or not.